# How to run Native Code of worklight in blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

In worklight, I tried to pull out the native code of android and run that in emulator supported by android sdk eclipse its working gud. Now i did the same thing in blackberry. 
I have downloaded Blackberry SDK using their plugin. But i tried to pull out the native code for blackberry from worklight. i cant do the same as what i did in android. Its not generating some files. How to run Worklight native code in Blackberry stimulator ?. Any Suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Worklight does not generate a native code for BlackBerry as it does for iOS/Android/WindowsPhone. Instead it's generating a BlackBerry WebWorks project, which is essentially a web application that would be run in the WebWorks container on a BlackBerry device.

You can read more about BlackBerry WebWorks application development at https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/

Also, you can get more info about developing BlackBerry apps with Worklight at 
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/

Refer to modules:

Module 02.3 - Setting Up Your BlackBerry Development Environment

Module 03.3 - Previewing your Application in BlackBerry environment

Comment: I read that modules during installation. I think for every environment there is be some ultimate end file be tere for example apk for android.. to build in windows project we need to call cs.proj.. like in same fashion i cant find that destination file for blackberry... In worklight its not generating .jdw during build the environment

Answer (score 1):

Some of the older versions of blackberry do not support hypens ('-') in the names of the files. If you have a hyphen in any of your files, even images, your blackberry environment in your Worklight application will not build and you will receive an error in your console when trying to build. Can you check to see if you are receiving this error?